# How to parse tokens of long lexer rule that cannot be converted into parser rule?

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to parse this with ANTLR4:

```
> A Request [AR]
Commments might have many lines here
Line 2
 
- A Response [A]
- The other response [B]
Response can also have lines here.

> Request [A]
- Responce
```

The following code parses it very well:

```
grammar Response;

prog: (request | response)+ EOF;

request: REQUEST TEXT*;
response: RESPONSE TEXT*;
 
REQUEST: '>' TEXT '[' ID ']';
RESPONSE: '-' TEXT ('[' ID ']')?;
 
ID: [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9._]*;
TEXT: ~[\r\n]+;
 
EMPTY: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

[image]

This is a good result. However I would like to parse separately the ID and TEXT. Because these are tokens in a long lexer rule, it seems this is not supported.

As I understand, usually in this case you can replace the lexer rules REQUEST and RESPONSE into parser rules like request_rule and response_rule.

But this does not work here, as then the TEXT lexer rule will match each and every line. For example, if I replace REQUEST and RESPONSE to ruleREQUEST and ruleRESPONSE:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to proceed... It seems that the only way is to make the code far more complicated using a number of popMode and pushMode, as described here:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2229 (incorrect lexer rule precedence with "not" rules)

Is there any simple way, based on the original antlr4 code to get the TEXT and ID values in C# Antlr4.Runtime.Standard? Other then that, the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEXT is greedy, so it matches above all other lexer rules. You will need to make it not greedy by adding a '?' operator after the '+'.

Once you do that, however, the parser rules will need to be changed to allow different tokens.

Here is a grammar that may work instead. It works for your input, but you may need to make further changes.

```
grammar Response;

prog: (request | response)+ EOF;
request: request_rule text*;
response: response_rule text*;
request_rule: '>' text '[' ID ']';
response_rule: '-' text ('[' ID ']')?;
text: (ID | TEXT)+;
ID: [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9._]*;
GT: '>';
LP: '[';
RP: ']';
DS: '-';
TEXT: ~[\r\n]+?;
EMPTY: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: Hmm, but you are right, it is parsed correctly if the listener ignores the multiple TEXT and ID tags under rule ```text```.

Comment: This is just one way of getting the input to parse. You could also try lexer modes, i.e. switch to a mode when a certain token is recognized, then switch back when finding a '>'.

Comment: Could I ask, in your code, why is the ```text``` rule set  as ```text: (ID | TEXT)+;```? It makes more sense to me if it was ```text: TEXT+;```. However, the second does not work.

Comment: In the original grammar `TEXT` would match ` A Request ' (and returned with `REQUEST`). In the new grammar, `text` must match `A` and `Request` tokens, which are both just `ID`. The string `A` could match ID or TEXT, but since they are the same length, the first "wins", i.e., `ID`. Likewise, for `Request`. Always print out the tokens and types. As I said, you could use "modes" to limit the set of token rules you want to match if that makes more sense for you. The input is consumed entirely before the parser gets really started, and so the parse context does not enter into lexing.